# Running independent sub-projects on one Play server doesn't work

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I'am trying to run multiple independent Play Framework 2.2 projects on one single Play server.
Problem is that when I use `run` or `start` to start the application, then the "sub"-project shows the content of the "root"-project. I have read everything avaliable, but I can't figure out a solution :/

Here's the `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val aaaroot = project.in(file(".")).aggregate(project1).dependsOn(project1)

lazy val project1 = project.in(file("project1"))
```

The `routes` file of the "root"-project:

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()

GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

->  /project1  project1.Routes
```

The `routes` file (called project1.routes) of the "sub"-project:

```
GET     /                           controllers.project1.Application.index()

GET     /assets/*file               controllers.project1.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

The `Application.java` Controller of the subproject uses `package controllers.project1;`

I also tried to set up the "Router object" in the application.conf file of the "sub"-project ( application.router=project1.Routes ). As described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/play-framework/multiple%2420projects/play-framework/O-lI0PsxM0U/eCFuBM4EdQMJ).

Every suggestion is highly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. The controller is used correctly, but there is a name-conflict with the views.

My Application.java says:

```
package controllers.project1;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;

import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Project1"));
    }

}
```

The error is the line `import views.html.*;`. This calls the views from the main-project. To avoid it I had to rename the view-folder to something else and edit the import like `import viewsofproject1.html.*;`